# jquery show select options based on parameters

Tags: jquery, forms, dropdown

I'm trying to create a form with a drop down that performs as follows:

- If a hidden field contains no value, show all select options.
- If a value exists in the hidden field, show only items that contain the value.

The hidden value is populated by a parameter.

My code so far is below, which doesn't work. In this example, assume that the hiddendealer input contains the value 'honda', so I would like to only display options with the word 'honda' in.

```
<select name="dealership-selection" id="dealer">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select your dealer</option>
    <option value="Fiat, Location 1">Fiat, Location 1</option>
    <option value="Honda, Location 1">Honda, Location 1</option>
    <option value="Honda, Location 2">Honda, Location 2/option>
    <option value="Kia, Location 1">Kia, Location 1</option>
    <option value="Peugeot, Location 1">Peugeot, Location 1</option>
    <option value="Peugeot, Location 2">Peugeot, Location 2</option>
    <option value="Škoda, Location 1">Škoda, Location 1</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="hiddendealer" value="">

<script>
    // get contents of hidden input; store in variable 
    var valDealer =  $("span.hiddendealer input").val(); 

    $('select#dealer option[value="' + valDealer + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected'); 

    if (valDealer.length == 1) {
        $('select#dealer option').each(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':contains("' + valDealer + '")')) {
                    console.log('this option contains the variable string');
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    console.log('this option does not contain the variable string');
                    $(this).hide();
                }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I neglected to mention this is on WordPress, using Contact Form 7 - it's a stripped back version of the select box.

Comment: Would be easiest if you put your option data into an array, then you can just filter the array from your input and then display the result.

Comment: What do you see in the console?  I believe your problem is the fact that `honda != Honda`

Comment: @Archer your prayers have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are problems with hiding the `<option>` element in HTML.
I would advice you to create an object with array of options, like

```
options = {
    honda: [
        { value: 1, text: 'Some text 1' },
        { value: 2 text: 'Some text 2' },
    ],
    kia: [
        { value: 3, text: 'Some text 3' },
        { value: 4 text: 'Some text 4' },
    ]
}
```

and then write a function that will REDRAW your select box, based on selected dealer (providing the visibleOptions), e.g.:

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {
            honda: [
                { value: 1, text: 'Some text 1' },
                { value: 2, text: 'Some text 2' },
            ],
            kia: [
                { value: 3, text: 'Some text 3' },
                { value: 4, text: 'Some text 4' },
            ]
        };

        function setDealer(dealer) {
            var visibleOptions = options[dealer];
            var place = $('#place');
            place.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < visibleOptions.length; i++) {
                // Do not forget to escape your data!
                // I am not doing this here, because it is just an example
                place.append(
                    '<option value="' + visibleOptions[i].value + '">'
                      + visibleOptions[i].text +
                    '</option>'
                );
            }
        }

        setDealer('honda');
        
        $('#dealer').change(function() {
           setDealer($(this).val());
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Dealer: <select name="dealer" id="dealer">
<option value="honda">Honda</option>
<option value="kia">Kia</option>
</select>
<select name="place" id="place"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to apply different actions to the options in dependence of their values. I also recommend you to perform case insensitive string comparison using [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method. In following example an option will be displayed only if it' value attribute contains specified substring.

```js
$("#dealer").change(function() {
  var search = $("#dealer").val().toLowerCase();
  $("[name=dealership] option")
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
      var option = $(this).attr('value').toLowerCase();
      return ~option.indexOf(search);
    })
    .show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="dealer">Dealer</label>
<input id="dealer" type="text">

<label for="dealers">Dealers</label>
<select name="dealership" id="dealers">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select your dealer</option>
  <option value="Fiat, Location 1">Fiat, Location 1</option>
  <option value="Honda, Location 1">Honda, Location 1</option>
  <option value="Honda, Location 2">Honda, Location 2/option>
  <option value="Kia, Location 1">Kia, Location 1</option>
  <option value="Peugeot, Location 1">Peugeot, Location 1</option>
  <option value="Peugeot, Location 2">Peugeot, Location 2</option>
  <option value="Škoda, Location 1">Škoda, Location 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This looks and works above as expected - I'll see about applying this today (hopefully) and see how I get on! Many thanks.